# Groups with no abelian centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group with no abelian centralizers. Is it true that $G$ must be a 2-group?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily the case. If $G$ is a group such that there are no abelian centralizers in $G$, then $G \times H$ also has this property for any group $H$.